# Can someone explain to me how this program works?

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I am having trouble understanding how to program below works and I would appreciate someone explaining to me how exactly it runs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Enter two number whose GCD needs to be calculated. 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Title of what program will do
    System.out.println("GCD Finder");
    System.out.println("");

    // Here user is instructed to enter the numbers
    System.out.println("Please enter first number: "); 
    int number1 = scanner.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Please enter second number: "); 
    int number2 = scanner.nextInt(); 

    // The numbers are then calculated using findGCD.
    System.out.println("GCD of two numbers " + number1 +" and " + number2 +" is : " + findGCD(number1,number2)); 
    } 


private static int findGCD(int number1, int number2) { 
    //base case 
    if(number2 == 0){ 
        return number1; 
        } 
    // Returns the two numbers 
    return findGCD(number2, number1%number2); 
    }
```

This part below is specifically what I am having trouble understanding.  Please do not hesitate to explain in detail, I want to understand it fully. Thank you for your time.

```
private static int findGCD(int number1, int number2) { 
    //base case 
    if(number2 == 0){ 
        return number1; 
        } 
    // Returns the two numbers 
    return findGCD(number2, number1%number2); 
    }
```

Comment: Standard response: Step through the program in your debugger, one line at a time, examining the variables as you go, until you understand the logic.

Comment: The down-voting seems harsh to me? recursion is often difficult until you "get" it. and stepping through with the debugger wouldn't necessarily help unless you knew what recursion was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the part you are in particular struggling with:

```
// A function which returns the greatest common divisor.
private static int findGCD(int number1, int number2) { 
    //base case 
    if(number2 == 0){ 
        return number1; 
        } 
    // Returns the two numbers 
    return findGCD(number2, number1%number2); 
}
```

This is a recursive function, which is i imagine what is causing you difficulty. To better understand recursive functions in general perhaps read this: http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php Don't worry that it uses python as an example.

In this case in particular the function will return number 1 when number 2 is 0. if number two isnt zero then it will call the function again with number2 being the remainder of number1 / number2, otherwise known as the modulus % https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

You could write the function in a while loop aswell:

```
//PSEUDOCODE WATCH YOURSELF

private static int findGCD(int n1, int n2) {
    int result = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(n2 == 0) {
            return result;
        }
        result = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = result-n2;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps a little?
Or at least doesn't make anything more confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the links this definitely helped me.  I don't know why people down voted instead of trying to help, I was close to deleting this question after the down votes and the last guys comment which didn't help me at all and seemed arrogant to me.

Comment: @John no worries, i'm glad it helped. Recursion is one of the first hurdles a lot of Computer Science students go through. Don't worry though, it will get easy to understand quickly enough.